# how can convert a base64 svg image to base64 image png

Tags: javascript

I have a code that converts a chart into svg. but I need the output format to be a PNG image. `svgString2Image` is the function that returns a codified base64 svg. How can I do it? thank you very much.

```
function svgString2Image( svgString, width, height, format, callback ) {
  //console.log("svgString",svgString)
    format ? format : 'png';

    var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa( unescape( encodeURIComponent( svgString ) ) ); // Convert SVG string to data URL
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        context.clearRect ( 0, 0, width, height );
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

        canvas.toBlob( function(blob) {
            var filesize = Math.round( blob.length/1024 ) + ' KB';
            if ( callback ) callback( blob, filesize );
        });

    };
    ///****************************
  document.getElementById('my_image').src=imgsrc;
    return image.src = imgsrc;

}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lPhmuYywPCdjQrnwhQcH?p=preview

Comment: Use the callback.

Comment: @meager How does linked Question and Answers address issue at code at current Question?

Comment: `format` is never used but canvas.toBlob default is 'image/png'. If you want to specify the format add `'image/' + format` as the 2nd parameter to canvas.toBlob.

Comment: @WilliamLohan I'm not sure what you're saying, how can I fix it to generate a base64 string for a png

Comment: Use [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) if you want a base64 and not a file

Comment: where? , how can do it?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/x4Db6spSxdEAQEqoeAi1?p=preview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As both @guest271314 and I stated in the comments use [canvas.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) when base64 string is desired not, [canvas.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob). Also image.onload is async so it is impossible to "return" the base64 png string. You must use callback (or [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as @guest271314 stated).

```
function svgString2Image(svgString, width, height, format, callback) {
    // set default for format parameter
    format = format ? format : 'png';
    // SVG data URL from SVG string
    var svgData = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgString)));
    // create canvas in memory(not in DOM)
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // get canvas context for drawing on canvas
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // set canvas size
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    // create image in memory(not in DOM)
    var image = new Image();
    // later when image loads run this
    image.onload = function () { // async (happens later)
        // clear canvas
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        // draw image with SVG data to canvas
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
        // snapshot canvas as png
        var pngData = canvas.toDataURL('image/' + format);
        // pass png data URL to callback
        callback(pngData);
    }; // end async
    // start loading SVG data into in memory image
    image.src = svgData;
}

// call svgString2Image function
svgString2Image(svgString, 800, 600, 'png', /* callback that gets png data URL passed to it */function (pngData) {
    // pngData is base64 png string
});
```

Comment: thanks! can I get the base64 string without using a callback, for example: `var png=svgString2Image(svgString, 800, 600, 'png)`

Comment: "Also image.onload is async so it is impossible to "return" the base64 png string. You must use callback (or Promise as @guest271314 stated)." - from answer please read

Comment: Okay, I wanted to know if there was another method. thank you very much.

Comment: Not that I know of. The only way I know is how you are doing it, drawing the image to a canvas and calling toSomthing() on the canvas (in this case toDataURL). You have to wait for the Image to load in the original data (SVG data in this case) before you draw it to the canvas ie the image.onload function. This makes the whole process async.

Answer (score 1):

No function is passed to `svgString2Image` at last argument. Pass a function to `svgString2Image` which expects `blob` and `filesize` arguments.

Comment: can you help me with that? I just need to return the result in an image in base64 png

Comment: What do you mean by `return`? You composed the function; what is the purpose of `callback`? `svgString2Image( svgString, 800, 600, 'png', function(blob, filesize) {//do stuff with blob and filesize} );`

Comment: It means, return the string base64 in png. I have no purpose with that part of the code. I had it in case this could help to generate the string in png.

Comment: Why do you use `canvas.toBlob()` is the expected result is a `data URI`? It is not possible to `return` from within an asynchronous function, though you can use `Promise` to return a `Promise` object from the function call and `.then()` to get the value of the fulfilled `Promise`